# background-color getting inherited from body element

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have two `stacked` elements with footer

```
.background
.container-fluid 
.footer
```

Please see my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/z9Unk/309/

I expect green to be shown in background with footer in the bottom.

But it shows black (background-color of body). Why is that?

If I remove background-color from `body`, then it shows the green background.

How can I show the green background without removing `background-color` from body?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got `z-index:-1;` on `.my-world-background`. `body` has `z-index:0;` by default so it's rendered in front.

Comment: I thought that as well. What is the solution...do I need to set z-index on body? that might break my rest of the site I am afraid. Any other solution??

Comment: You can add `z-index: -2; position: relative;` to `body` if that does not mess up anything else.

Comment: What is the point of setting a z-index of -1 on that div anyway... just remove it.

Comment: I need to custom display my background on certain pages behind main content (container-fluid). Hence I need to stack it behind.

Answer (score 2):

Use background-color instead of color

```
.footer-content {
  text-align:center;
  font-size:22px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: He _is_ using `background-color`.

Comment: "I expect green to be shown in background", so he is not talking about the footer.

Comment: "How can I show the green background without removing background-color from body? " I think he's talking about the footer but maybe he can explain better :p

Comment: No I am not talking abt footer

Answer (score 0):

The `.my-world-background` div is behind the body div so the background color for `body` is taking precedence. This is why you see green when your remove the `background-color` property from body.  Meanwhile the footer doesn't have a `background-color` property set, only a color property which refers to the color of text.  Perhaps this is what you want:

http://jsfiddle.net/WSwjy/